# Flex (with Zend) running on a IIS-Server

Tags: php, apache-flex, zend-framework, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Flex-Page which connects to a MySQL-DB through PHP (Zend). I run the Flex-Page on an IIS-Server (Windows Server 2008 R2) and it works. But the problem is, that i specified the web root to the C:\inetpub\wwwroot directory (there php is running). On the server i want it on another directory. (Now i have the main Flex Page in the directory für the webserver, and the php files are in the wwwroot directory).

When i specify the web root to an other directory, nothing works, not even on my local machine.

I hope you know what my problem is.. ^^ (sorry for my bad english)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what "specify the web root to an other directory" means. Where did you specify the web root? What isn't working?  Are your files not being served to the browser?  Or have your remote calls stopped working?  or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set up a virtual directory on IIS if you want your files served from other than the web root. So google "IIS virtual directory add".